# Can't query E.164 phone numbers in Firebase via REST API (due to '+' character)

Tags: firebase

I am storing phone numbers in Firebase in the [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format, which means they are strings beginning with a plus sign.  But I am unable to successfully query the REST API if there's a '+' in the string.

So if I post this data:

```
$ curl -X POST 'https://<firebaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json' \
  -d '{"deviceId": "999", "phoneNumber": "+16171234567"}'
=> {"name":"-KAE4sYw45VUehwUOoBp"}
```

resulting in this data structure:

- **users**

  - **-KAE4sYw45VUehwUOoBp**

    - **deviceId:** "999"
    - **phoneNumber:** "+16171234567"

where I have indexed both the `deviceId` and `phoneNumber` fields, then the following query works:

```
$ curl -X GET 'https://<firebaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="deviceId"&equalTo="999"'
=> {"-KAE4sYw45VUehwUOoBp":{"deviceId":"999","phoneNumber":"+16171234567"}}
```

But querying the phone number field in the same way returns nothing:

```
$ curl -X GET 'https://<firebaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="phoneNumber"&equalTo="+16171234567"'
=> {}
```

I have tried various forms of URL encoding or escaping the '+' symbol but cannot get a phone number query to return successfully.

```
$ curl -X GET 'https://<firebaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="phoneNumber"&equalTo="%2B16171234567"'
=> {}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of your Firebase data structure?

Comment: Yep, I added a description of the data structure resulting from the POST, as it would appear in the Firebase web console.

Comment: Did you solve it?